# Laravel 5: update Controller in Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there any way to access (modify) `$request` "protected proprieties" in the Middleware, to modify requested Controller:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // change $request parameter
    // $request->server->parameters->REQUEST_URI = "something else";

    return $next($request);
}
```

I want to override requested Controller if Cache is valid for the request,

thanks,

Comment: Why not just use a redirect?

Comment: can u provide example pls,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the page in the middleware by returning a redirect.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // change $request parameter
    // $request->server->parameters->REQUEST_URI = "something else";
    if ($request->something === 'anything')
        return redirect()->to("/something-else");

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Update:**
If you do not wish for the url to update, you could invoke the controller directly using:

```
app(\App\Http\Controllers\MyController::class)->getMethod();
```

Where you update the Controller and the method to the ones you need.
However I would not recommend this.

Comment: Is there any solution without change URL?

Comment: I updated my answer. However, I would not recommend changing the page without changing the url.

Comment: pls, can u write full `handle` method code, in case of use second solution @Jerodev

Comment: just can't find a way to stop current requested Controller, I need to run (Only) the new controller

Comment: public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
     $cached = \App(Controllers\test::class)->test2();
     return response($cached);
    }